# "this.props.dispatch is not a function" when using redux-tooltip

Tags: reactjs, redux, tooltip

The below this.props.dispatch issue was fixed but now I am receiving an error message saying:

```html
Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Tooltip)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(Tooltip)".
▶ 25 stack frames were collapsed.
./src/index.js
C:/Users/rksny/Desktop/travelPlanner/src/index.js:11
   8 | import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
   9 | 
  10 | 
> 11 | ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
  12 | registerServiceWorker();
  13 | 
  14 |
```

I keep receiving "this.props.dispatch" is not a function while using redux-tooltip. This is my first time trying to utilizing redux so maybe I am missing something obvious. I'm essentially trying to copy the react simple maps example found here: https://www.react-simple-maps.io/with-redux-tooltip.

The error message is:

```html
TypeError: this.props.dispatch is not a function
  20 | handleMove(geography, evt) {
  21 |   const x = evt.clientX
  22 |   const y = evt.clientY + window.pageYOffset
> 23 |   this.props.dispatch(
  24 |     show({
  25 |       origin: { x, y },
  26 |       content: geography.properties.name,
```

Code snippet:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import withRedux from "next-redux-wrapper"
import { ComposableMap, ZoomableGroup, Geographies, Geography } from "react-simple-maps";
import { WorldMapData } from '../Utils/Data';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {
  Tooltip,
  actions,
} from "redux-tooltip"

import { initStore } from './stores';

const { show, hide } = actions

class WorldMap extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.handleMove = this.handleMove.bind(this)
    this.handleLeave = this.handleLeave.bind(this)
  }
  handleMove(geography, evt) {
    const x = evt.clientX
    const y = evt.clientY + window.pageYOffset
    this.props.dispatch(
      show({
        origin: { x, y },
        content: geography.properties.name,
      })
    )
  }
  handleLeave() {
    this.props.dispatch(hide())
  } 

 render() {
  return (
   <div >
    <div className='' style={{height: '18vh'}}>
     <p className="black b f1 f-headline-ns tc db mb3 mb4-ns" title="Home">Travel Planner</p>
     <p className='black f2'>select dream destination below</p>
    </div>
   <div>
    <ComposableMap className='ba' style={{width: '90%', height: 'auto', maxHeight: '70vh'}}>
      <ZoomableGroup>
        <Geographies  geography={ WorldMapData }>
          {(geographies, projection) => geographies.map(geography => (
            <Geography 
             key={ geography.id } 
             geography={ geography } 
             projection={ projection } 
                      onMouseMove={this.handleMove}
                      onMouseLeave={this.handleLeave}
             style={{
                       default: {      
                         fill: "#ECEFF1",
                         stroke: "#607D8B",
                         strokeWidth: 0.75,
                         outline: "none",
                       },
                       hover: {
                         fill: "#607D8B",
                         stroke: "#607D8B",
                         strokeWidth: 0.75,
                         outline: "none",
                       },
                       pressed: {
                         fill: "#FF5722",
                         stroke: "#607D8B",
                         strokeWidth: 0.75,
                         outline: "none",
                       },
                   }}
             onClick = {this.props.onRouteChange}
            />
          ))}
        </Geographies>
      </ZoomableGroup>
    </ComposableMap>
    <Tooltip />
    </div>
   </div>
  )
 }
}


export default withRedux(initStore)(WorldMap);
```

If helpful here is a link to the gh-pages where the app is posted: 
https://rksnyder7.github.io/travelPlanner/

Comment: Any specific reason that you are using "next-redux-wrapper" ? I recommend you to sue react-redux library to connect your component with redux store.

Comment: If you install react-redux and then add at the top of your component `import {connect} from 'react-redux'`, then at the end of your file you add `const reduxWrapperWorldMap = connect()(WorldMap)` and right next to it `export default withRedux(initStore)(reduxWrapperWorldMap );` to see if now you have access to dispatch in your props? Please let us know if it works?

Comment: Thank you that removed the dispatch error, but now I am receiving the following error: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Tooltip)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(Tooltip)".  it happens when I add <Tooltip /> after </ComposableMap>

Comment: Please update the question with your most recent change to show us what your current code looks like

Comment: I updated the above question with the new error and current code.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your component and base class with props. Initially you should bind it and make calls in constructor.

```
 constructor(props) {
   super(props)
   this.handleMove = this.handleMove.bind(this)
   this.handleLeave = this.handleLeave.bind(this)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, then it seems you're trying to access `dispatch()` directly, rather than via the store (that `withRedux` injects into your component). Consider the following updates to your code:

```
handleMove(geography, evt) {

  const x = evt.clientX
  const y = evt.clientY + window.pageYOffset

  this.props.store.dispatch( // [UPDATE] Add store
    show({
      origin: { x, y },
      content: geography.properties.name,
    })
  )
}

handleLeave() {

  this.props.store.dispatch(hide()) // [UPDATE] Add store
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this fixed the dispatch issue but now I am receiving a new error with the connect(tooltip). I added the error to the top of the post.

Comment: push your latest code to git - should be able to help you then

Comment: Ok it's updated on git now, thanks for the help really appreciate it!

Comment: Any further insights??

Comment: No sorry - seems there are lots of errors in the way this project is setup. The store is not setup correctly, the tooltip middleware is not added correctly, etc. Perhaps you could create your own simpler tooltip component?